# Validate inputform for float with 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, html

i want to check with Javascript a user input in html for float with 2 decimal. Only 0-9 and 1 x ',' should be allowed. If there is no ',', i want to insert ',00'.

For example:

1234 -> 1234,00

123f    -> 123,00

1234,12 -> 1234,12

123a4,15 -> 1234,15

1234,1525,23 -> 12341525,23

Great would be additional a separator four thousand, but that's nice to have

12341525,23 -> 12.341.525,23

Because of that, i can't use:

```
<input type="number" name="abc" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Are you trying to verify input, or transform input?

Comment: Great. Thank you Louys Patrice Bessette and Joels Elf. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check that there is no more than one comma. If there is no comma or not enough digits after the comma, it will add in the comma and zeros. It also checks that the fractional and integral parts are numbers.

```
x = document.getElementById("abc").value;
if(x.indexOf(",") != x.lastIndexOf(",")) {
  //Invalid, there is more than one comma
} else {
  var comma = x.indexOf(",");
  if(comma == -1) {
    x = x.concat(",00"); // No comma
  } else if(comma == x.length - 1) {
    x = x.concat("00"); // comma, no digits after it though
  } else if(comma == x.length - 2) {
    x = x.concat("0"); // comma with 1 digit after it
  }
  if(comma <= x.length - 3) { 
    var parts = x.split(",");
    if(isNaN(parts[0]) || isNaN(parts[1])) {
      //Invalid, either the integral part or the fractional part is not a number
    }
  } else {
    // Invalid, the comma comes before more than two digits
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is what you want.
It sets a thousand separator too.

Note that the decimal separator is usually a dot and the thousand separator usually a comma. ;)

Maybe there is a shorter way to do it only with regular expressions...
But the code below works.

```
<input id="foo" type="text" onchange="formatNumber();" onkeyup="onlyNumbers();">
<script>
function formatNumber(){
    // define separators
    thousandSep=".";
    decimalSep=",";

    // get the input
    n=document.getElementById("foo").value;

    // Format decimals
    n=parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);
    decimals=decimalSep+n.substr(n.length-2);

    // Temporarly remove the decimals and count how many thousand groups there is
    n=parseInt(n).toString();
    thousandGroups=parseInt(Math.ceil(n.length/3));

    //Place the thousand separator between each group of 3 digits
    for(i=1;i<thousandGroups;i++){
        j=i-1;
        n=n.substr(0,n.length-(3*i+j))+thousandSep+n.substr(n.length-(3*i+j));
    }

    // return the formated number
    document.getElementById("foo").value=n+decimals;
}

function onlyNumbers(){
    n=document.getElementById("foo").value;

    // Check if last keyboard input is a digit... Accepts dots
    if(n.substr(n.length-1).search(/^[\d\.]/i)!=-1){
        document.getElementById("foo").value=n;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("foo").value=n.substr(0,n.length-1)
    }
}
</script>
```